# Florida Condo Law and Kickbacks

Tags: florida, hoa

[Florida Condo Law Statute 1682](https://www.flsenate.gov/Session/Bill/2017/01682/?Tab=VoteHistory) prohibits

> an officer, director, or manager of a condominium association from soliciting, offering to accept, or accepting a kickback for which consideration has not been provided;

Q1) If my CAM (Community Association Manager) provides me with compensated jobs or work, am I running afoul of said statute?  Assume I am a board member.

Q2) Does the statute prohibit the the CAM from soliciting or accepting referral fees (kickbacks) from vendors such as groundkeepers, pool maintenance service etc.?

Answer (score 3):

If you are given a paid job, and you do the work, then "consideration has been provided", and 1682 will not apply.

As to "referral fees" those sound more like kickbacks, but it depends on what, if anything, the person gets for the fee.